# 'train' and 'class' have different lengths error in R

Tags: r, knn

I just wanted to conduct a kNN classification with the situation when k is 3. I would like to predict the dependent variable “diabetes” in valid set using train set and calculate the accuracy.

But I faced to the error message with

`Error in knn(train = TrainXNormDF, test = ValidXNormDF, cl = MLdata2[,  :  'train' and 'class' have different lengths`

I can't solve this problem with get approach with

```
for(i in ((length(MLValidY) + 1):length(TrainXNormDF)))+(MLValidY = c(MLValidY, 0))
```

What can I do for it? Please help.

My code is as like below

```
install.packages("mlbench")
install.packages("gbm")

library(mlbench)
library(gbm)

data("PimaIndiansDiabetes2")
head(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)

MLdata <- as.data.frame(PimaIndiansDiabetes2)
head(MLdata)
str(MLdata)
View(MLdata)

any(is.na(MLdata))
sum(is.na(MLdata))

MLdata2 <- na.omit(MLdata)
any(is.na(MLdata2))
sum(is.na(MLdata2))
View(MLdata2)

MLIdx <- sample(1:3, size = nrow(MLdata2), prob = c(0.6, 0.2, 0.2), replace = TRUE)

MLTrain <- MLdata2[MLIdx == 1,]
MLValid <- MLdata2[MLIdx == 2,]
MLTest <- MLdata2[MLIdx == 3,]

head(MLTrain)
head(MLValid)
head(MLTest)

str(MLTrain)
str(MLValid)
str(MLTest)

View(MLTestY)


MLTrainX <- MLTrain[ , -9]
MLValidX <- MLValid[ , -9]
MLTestX <- MLTest[ , -9]

MLTrainY <- as.data.frame(MLTrain[ , 9])
MLValidY <- as.data.frame(MLValid[ , 9])
MLTestY <- as.data.frame(MLTest[ , 9])

View(MLTrainX)
View(MLTrainY)

library(caret)

NormValues <- preProcess(MLTrainX, method = c("center", "scale"))

TrainXNormDF <- predict(NormValues, MLTrainX)
ValidXNormDF <- predict(NormValues, MLValidX)
TestXNormDF <- predict(NormValues, MLTestX)

head(TrainXNormDF)
head(ValidXNormDF)
head(TestXNormDF)


install.packages('FNN')
library(FNN)
library(class)

NN <- knn(train = TrainXNormDF, 
      test = ValidXNormDF,
      cl = MLValidY,
      k = 3)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `cl` variable is not the same length as your `train` variable. `MLValidY` only has 74 observations, while `TrainXNormDF` has 224.

`cl` should provide the true classification for every row in your training set.

Furthermore, `cl` is a data.frame instead of a vector.

Try the following:

```
NN <- knn(train = TrainXNormDF, 
      test = ValidXNormDF,
      cl = MLTrainY$`MLTrain[, 9]`,
      k = 3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for details. I'm not really familiar with R so I was struggled with it. And you saved me! I deepley appreciative to you.

Comment: No problem, I remember running into similar problems when first using FNN package.

Comment: But I got the another problem with Warning message as like this : Warning messages:
1: In `==.default`(NN, MLTrainY$`MLTrain[, 9]`) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length    for finding accuracy...   It is just Warning so may I just ignore it?

Comment: It ran ok for me, with no warning messages. Try running again from the beginning to make sure you haven't changed any objects in the meantime, and make sure you paste the code above exactly. Also check the length of your objects: `nrow(TrainXNormDF)` and `length(MLTrainY$'MLTrain[, 9]')` should both give 224.

Answer (score 0):

As @rw2 stated, it's the length of `cl`. I think you meant to use `MLtrainY`, not `MLvalidY`. When you have a single column data frame, you can still run into shape problems (converts it to a vector). You could walk back to make sure that you use the right content here, like so:

```
NN <- knn(train = TrainXNormDF, 
          test = ValidXNormDF,
          cl = MLdata2[MLIdx == 1,]$diabetes, # shape no longer an issue
          k = 3)
```